# Стопятьсот (100500)

Tags: числительные

What does it mean when Russian say: "Здесь стопятьсот графиков, что с ними делать?"

Comment: This sounds like coming from [olbanian](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%96%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's an Internet meme basically meaning "a lot" but in a funny way. The fun is two-way (pun intended): *сто пятьсот* sounds totally wrong while resembling regular *сто пятьдесят* (and it having been written as *стопицот* messes it up even more), and *100500* being read as *сто пятьсот* is also comically wrong.

I suppose it comes from child talk--children often mix up large numbers, so it's not uncommon to hear things like that.

Comment: +1. In the Old Cyrillic alphabet numbers were written with letters, like in Hebrew and Greek, in those times 100 was written as `P` and 500 as `Ф`, so стопятьсот should be written as `РФ` which looks highly symbolic. :P

Comment: @YellowSky Do you know Cyrillic numerals by heart? What about Hebrew, is it that symbolic in it too? :)

Comment: I know, but not all of them, now this knowledge is not actually needed. Cyrillic letters as numerals aren't as symbolic as Hebrew ones, Slavs aren't that much into numerology as Kabbalists are. You can nowadays only see Cyrillic letters used as numerals in the Bible written in the Church-Slavonic to mark the numbers of the chapters and verses, nothing else. There's another interesting thing about the Cyrillic alphabet, the names of the letters. Each letter is named with a Church Slavonic word, and some sequences of the letters make sensible phrases.

Comment: Like A-Б-В is Азъ-Боукы-Вѣдѣ (I-Letters-Know), К-Л-М is Како-Людие-Мыслете (Like-People-Think), Р-С-Т Рьци-Слово-Тврьдо (Say-Word-Firmly), etc.

Comment: An interesting parallel can be made with the Javanese syllabary, which, if pronounced according to the sequence of its letters, makes a sensible phrase in Javanese, "Hana caraka, data sawala, paḍa jayanya, maga baṭanga," which means, "There were (two) emissaries, they began to fight, their valor was equal, they both fell dead."

Answer (score 9):

According to [Russian Lurkmore](https://lurkmore.to/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%BE%D1%82) this is Russian equivalent of English ["OVER 9000"](http://wikireality.ru/wiki/Over_9000):

> Очень много — это примерно стопицот. Иногда применяется как коэффициент для сравнения: «больше в стопицот раз». Или даже: «больше в стопицот тысяч раз». Ещё используется как усиленная версия фразы «+1» в комментариях, подчёркивающая полное согласие с автором: «+ стопицот».

It was invented and become popular as a part of "язык падонкаф", origins of which go back to pre-internet time. One of the sites of this community was udaff.com, many others do not exist or changed their content. The oldest of the sites was fuck.ru and (according to Maksim Krongaus) it was created [back in 1998](http://modernlib.ru/books/maksim_krongauz/samouchitel_olbanskogo/read_2/):

> Падонки – это сетевая контркультура, сформировавшаяся на нескольких сайтах, многих из которых уже не существует. Первым таким сайтом стал fuck.ru. Потом открывались и закрывались сайты idiot.ru, fackru.net, down.ru.
> Сайт fuck.ru создали в 1998 году Егор Лавров и Константин Рыков.

The oldest examples of usage I could found are dating back 2004 and 2005:

> Udaff.com comment, dated [27-01-2005](http://udaff.com/print_c/read/creo/40773/page1.html):
> Вот блять **стопицот** раз такое четал, а фсёравно- ностальжи, блядь!!!
>
> Ladadriver.ru forum comment, dated [03.12.04](http://www.ladadriver.ru/2004-12/page-94.htm):
> Прикольно, ведро 96-го года, цвет розовый металлик, а выглядит она в **стопицот** раз свежее моей баклажановой девятины, которую я забарыжил во вторник.

As of the oldest origins of the phrase, the Lurkmore.to site has two versions. One version is that for the first time in TV-show "OSP-studio" or by Alexei Kortnev (leader of "Несчастный случай" band):

> Возможно, фраза впервые была исполнена в педераче ОСП-студия персонажем, которого изображал некто Сивохо (стопицот миллионов), либо в педераче «Несчастный случай» (Алексей Кортнев), в ролике про мальчика, который, с его слов: «победил стопетцот врагов».

As idea of the youtube show +100500 came to its creator in the [summer of 2010](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/+100500) this proves that the origin of the meme was not the title of this show.

Comment: +100500 . . . . . .

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the original pun was that a person desired to name a big number and said "100" but quickly realized it is too small and desired to change it to "150" on the fly but in the process realized it is again too small, so changed the "50" part to "500". So the number looks like being rising in the process of being pronounced.

Answer (score -3):

стопятьсот = очень много

it came from the name of popular videos from youtube

http://www.youtube.com/user/AdamThomasMoran

Comment: [Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/+100500) говорит что передача названа по мему, а не мем по названию передачи. Исходный ответ ovgolovin содержал эту ссылку, но потом она была убрана.

Comment: хм... может быть.... но это из той серии когда хрен разберешь что раньше курица или яйцо

Comment: Вот [здесь](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/+100500) пишут что идея шоу появилась летом 2010 года. А [здесь](http://a.farit.ru/i/t-104932.html) - обсуждение на форуме по поводу того откуда это выражение взялось датированное мартом 2009. Так что никак не "курица и яйцо".

Comment: источник достовернейший)

Comment: Для начала сойдет. Я нашел упоминания 100500 от 2004 года (см. мой ответ), а если вам удастся найти выпуски шоу раньше 2010 - выкладывайте ссылки сюда.